# Expanding Patterns in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I designed a logo that contained a simple line pattern the I expanded the pattern so when I enlarge or reduce the logo's size the location or the space between the line won't change.
After that the software became laggy and slow.
Why is that?

-guy

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see exactly what you mean, but with the information you have provided, it sounds like you are creating a large number of  paths, which could be slowing the program down. If these lines are stroked, and you want to scale them properly without having them keep a static width, go into your settings, and check the box that says "scale strokes and effects". It should be under general settings in the first settings panel that pops up.